# Send an email but not received

Tags: php, email

I'm tring to send an email via php

Here is the code:

```
<?php
//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'xxx@example.com';
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test email'; 
//define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
$message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail."; 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: xxx@example.com";
//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

But the message is not received in my email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to suppress error messages using @, you need to see these errors.

If you are testing this locally you need a mail server to be running. I use [Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/), it's dead simple.

Also note that [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) returning `true` does not indicate that the mail was successfully sent, only that execution of the command didn't generate an error:

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

Answer (score 1):

Are you executing this script on your local machine, or on a webserver with SMTP availability? If it's on your own computer, you may not have a mail server it can use.

Consider using PHPMailer instead, it is far more capable than the native `mail()` function, and includes integrated SMTP support: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code:

```
mail($address, $subject, $message, "From: Service <service@service.net>\n".
                                   "MIME-Version: 1.0\n".
                                   "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n");
```

Maybe the the correct carrige return in the headers is important

Comment: it makes a difference if you are using qotes or double qotes
in this case i am using double qotes and let php do the carrige return correctly.
This code is really proven to be correct.
If this doesn't work then the server isn't configured correctly